# ESP-IDF's equivalent of Arduino's WiFiClient.write() fucntionality

Tags: arduino, esp32, http-streaming, esp-idf

I'm using ESP32-CAM for video streaming using ESP-IDF framework. I was able to create server on ESP32-CAM and stream video sucessfully. For streaming I'm using HTTP protocol with `Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n` headers and it's working great :)

Now, I want to add a servo motor to the camera to adjust pan remotely. I think of 2 ways to do it.

1. Create another endpoint for servo, but for that I need to disconnect video streaming untill servo request is completed. This gives significant lag in video.
2. send data in between video streaming connection and get minimum lag in video.

I was able to use 2nd option in Arduino IDE for `WebServer`, there we have an option of [reading binary data from client in an ongoing request](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/wifi/client.read/). Example below

```
// only showing the relevent code ...
// create server.
WebServer server(80);
// then register different endpoint handlers ...
// ...
// ...

void video_stream_handler(){
  // initilize camera stuff, nothing to worry here
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
  uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
  char buf[32];
  sensor_t* sensor_settings = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  sensor_settings->set_framesize(sensor_settings, FRAMESIZE_VGA);
  sensor_settings->set_quality(sensor_settings, 20);
  
  // get client handle
  WiFiClient client = server.client();

  // now we can write headers as well as data to client. this works in ESP-IDF as well :)
  client.write(<some-headers>, <header-length>); 

  // now this is interesting.
  // we can read from client as well
  client.read(); // gives bytes read from client
```

My question is, is it possible with esp-idf to do something like this?
Or if there is any other better alternative than all of it? I want minimum lag in video streaming while still performing servo action in between.

Hardware: ESP32-CAM(single core) with 4MB PSRAM

[ESP-IDF http_server reference](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/c2ccc383dae2a47c2c2dc8c7ad78175a3fd11361/examples/protocols/http_server/simple/main/main.c)

P.S. I'm using Python socket to read/process the video stream and to send binary data in ongoing connection.

Comment: You can do anything you want in eap-idf. :) You could look at the source for Arduino `Client.Write` as I think under the hood it uses esp-idf. But I think it's just opening a socket and sending a packet.

Comment: Btw did you try accessing another endpoint while video is streaming? I'm not sure if it blocks or whether it would handle it in parallel.

Comment: @lurker I can access single endpoint at a time. The other one waits until current endpoint is served and because it's an infinite stream, it never ends ...